# zend navigation breadcrumbs to bypass ACL

Tags: zend-framework, breadcrumbs, zend-navigation

I make use of Zend_Navigation and its menu helper and breadcrumbs helper together with Zend_Acl. This all works as expected. But is it possible to ignore the acl on the breadcrumbs only?

My goal is to render a different view when access is denied on a certain page (this works) but I want the breadcrumbs to show nonetheless. They are empty now.

Is there any way of achieving this without using two different containers?

thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you post the way you made zend_navigation, zend_acl work together? I created an xml file in the config folder, initiated the navigation in the bootstrap and the navigation shows correct. But all menu items are shown for each role... Any help would be apreciated ;) Regards Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view page:

```
$this->navigation()->setUseAcl(false);
// or like this
$this->navigation()->setUseAcl(false)->breadcrumbs();
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked by doing the following: 
$this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setUseAcl(false);